# Issue using send with '-' to perform subtraction in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am building a calculator using Polish/prefix notation and I'm running into a peculiar problem.  When the program hits a subtraction operator, it throws `undefined method '-' for Fixnum (NoMethodError)`.  This only occurs with `-`; addition, multiplication, and division all work fine.  What's even stranger is that when I manually call `send` with `:-` in irb, the error doesn't occur.  The error only occurs when I run my program.

```
def calc(exp)
  exp = exp.split(" ")
  operands = []
  exp.reverse.each do |str|
    if is_operator?(str)
      op1 = operands.pop
      op2 = operands.pop
      str = str.to_sym
      result = op1.send str, op2
      operands.push(result)
    else
      operands.push(str.to_i)
    end
  end

  operands.pop
end

def is_operator?(char)
  char.to_i.to_s != char
end

exp = "− * / 15 − 7 + 1 1 3 + 2 + 1 1"
calc(exp)

test.rb:13:in `block in calc': undefined method `−' for 7:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Could you post your `is_operator?` method? Some input/output cases would be helpful as well. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please let us also see the invocation of your function (which `exp` you're testing with). We need to be able to reproduce your problem to answer you. Your code works fine for me for `calc("- 2 1")`.

Comment: Thanks, @JustinHellreich and @Amadan.  Added `is_operator?` and the case in which it's failing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `−` isn't a `-`. Here's the error I get when I paste your code directly into Ruby (`pbpaste | ruby` on OS X).

```
undefined method `"\u2212"' for 7:Fixnum
(repl):9:in `block in calc'
(repl):4:in `each'
(repl):4:in `calc'
(repl):24:in `<main>'
```

`"\u2212"` is [U+2212 MINUS SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm), which is not the same as the familiar [U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm). The latter is the character you (usually) get when you press the <kbd>-</kbd> key on your keyboard and the character used for the name of the `Fixnum#-` method.

If we replace your string with this one, which uses a regular `-`:

```
exp = "- * / 15 - 7 + 1 1 3 + 2 + 1 1"
```

...it works fine. See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/GFH0

Another way to demonstrate the issue is this:

```
p 7.send("\u002d", 3) # => 4
p 7.send("\u2212", 3) # => NoMethodError
```

How did you end up with `−`s instead of `-`s? I have no idea, but I'd wager you either copied-and-pasted it from somewhere or you're using a text editor that's not intended for programming and which has some "smart text" features that automatically replaces e.g. `""` with `“”` and `-` with `−`.

Why did my error message (and repl.it's) show `"\u2212"` when yours showed `"−"`? Perhaps a difference in Ruby versions (I used 2.3.1, as does repl.it) or different behavior depending on the encoding set in your shell.

Comment: The arithmetic operators in Ruby, as in most languages, come from the basic ASCII repertoire, not the much newer Unicode mathematics ranges. I believe Perl 6 allows U+2122 MINUS SIGN as a synonym for U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, but that's the only language that comes to mind.

Comment: @MarkReed I wouldn't have put it past Perl, but when I tried `perl -e "15 − 7"` (with Perl 5) I got an "Unrecognized character \xE2" error (0xE2 being the first byte of U+2212 in UTF-8: 0xE2 0x88 0x92).

Comment: Yeah, not 5. Perl 6 went out of its way to be Unicode-native.

Comment: Ah, yep, just tried Perl 6 and it works. `print(3×5)` even works! But `print(3✕5)` doesn't. Oh, Perl.

Comment: I feel like a total dunce.  You got it - I had copied and pasted the string from an example.  Thanks for your help.